# Delay in c# not thread.sleep

Tags: c#, .net

Guys is there any option in c# like in VB?

```
Sub Delay(ByVal dblSecs As Double)

Const OneSec As Double = 1.0# / (1440.0# * 60.0#)
Dim dblWaitTil As Date
Now.AddSeconds(OneSec)
dblWaitTil = Now.AddSeconds(OneSec).AddSeconds(dblSecs)
Do Until Now > dblWaitTil
Application.DoEvents() ' Allow windows messages to be processed
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a busy wait - the absolute worst among the many ways of making a delay.

Comment: It looks like you're doing: `DateTime dblWaitTil = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(dblSecs); while (DateTime.Now < dblWaitTil) { }`. It will be a very "busy" (resource consuming) loop.

Comment: *Why* do you want to delay? I ask because your answer might prompt a better solution than simply delaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do the same thing in C#, but that is a very bad idea.

This way of making a pause is called a busy loop, because it will make the main thread use as much CPU as possible.

What you want to do instead is to set up a timer, and call a callback method from the tick event:

```
public void Wait(double seconds, Action action) {
  Timer timer = new Timer();
  timer.Interval = (int)(seconds * 1000.0);
  timer.Tick += (s, o) => {
    timer.Enabled = false;
    timer.Dispose();
    action();
  };
  timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

Usage example:

```
textbox.text = "Test";
Wait(5.0, () => {
  textbox.text = "Finish";
});
```

Comment: i want link this textbox.text = "Test"; delay(5 second) then textbox.text = "Finish"; isa there any other good way to do this ?

Comment: This is async, and it will not really wait. If your program finishes before interval, code of callback will never be called. I'm not sure that OP wanted such behavior.

Comment: @SergeyS: Yes, it's async, that's how you do things like this in an event driven environment. What do you propose instead? The busy loop?

Comment: I propose Thread.Sleep() for him, but if he is ok with busy loop, why not?)

Comment: @SergeyS: `Thread.Sleep` won't work, it will freeze up the program while waiting.

Comment: If you say so - you don't understand OP's initial code. It waits for the interval and only after that proceed.

Comment: @SergeyS: I do understand the code, but obviously you don't.

Answer (score 0):

You want [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) class or [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) class whichever suits your needs.

Comment: could you give example,i'm new to c#.. :(

Comment: Refer to the link attached, they have small example within them.

Answer (score 0):

Patterson algorithm will be suitable for dispatcher things i think.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sardinas%E2%80%93Patterson_algorithm